# NodeJS connection to MongoDB (on AWS C9) returns undefined db object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-cloud9

I'm learning how to code on Amazon's Cloud 9, and I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB database from NodeJS, but when I call the `connect()` function the `db` returned in the callback is undefined.  However, I can see that the data exists when I run `show dbs` in the mongo shell, and the mongo server is running without issue, and the `connect()` function itself doesn't throw any errors.

**index.js**: Here is my *index.js* file containing the MongDB connection (this file executes when I run `npm start` in the terminal):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb", function (err, db) {
 if (err){ console.log(err)}
 else{
    console.log("Connected!")
    console.log(db.name)
    }

 db.close()
})
```

**mongo shell** confirms the database exists (`sample` is the name of the collection):

```
use testdb
switched to db testdb
db.sample.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aed5fc7a44ab7d8a4efce2f"), "name" : "Luckyfield" }
```

**mongo server** is running as it says "waiting for connections on port 27017", and whenever I run the index.js file this server records the connection opening and closing in the terminal:

```
connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:43820 #16 (1 connection now open)
2018-05-05T11:07:16.128+0000 I NETWORK  [conn16] received client metadata     from 127.0.0.1:43820 conn16: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.0.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.91-40.57.amzn1.x86_64" }, platform: "Node.js v6.14.1, LE, mongodb-core: 3.0.7" }
2018-05-05T11:07:16.138+0000 I NETWORK  [conn16] end connection 127.0.0.1:43820 (0 connections now open)
```

When I replace `db.name` to just `db`, the console shows a MongoClient object full of data, although I don't know what it is. I also tried inserting or querying documents but again, db seems to be undefined.

In summary, when I run `npm start` in a separate terminal, the *index.js* file executes and prints `undefined` in the console, even though the connection is properly established and the data actually exists. Thank you for any help!

Comment: You're reading old tutorials. The Node driver v3.x series that you would have installed with `npm install mongodb` has a different connection method. See [connecting](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/reference/ecmascriptnext/connecting/) in the reference guide.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I found a tutorial on the link you sent, copied the code (adjusted the db reference to my own) and it still returned undefined. Do you think it has to do with the install method? I followed instructions 
[here](https://github.com/nax3t/aws-cloud9-instructions)